# Check Box Value Not Working in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have check box on oracle forms

Value when checked = 'Y'

Value when unchecked = 'N'

By default value unchecked

I create button and write code when check box value 'N' the show message. But when I pressed the button then did not show message. When I changed the value to 'Y' then show message

**CODE:**

```
IF :WE_GROUP.CHECK_BOX_HOF = 'N' THEN
 MESSAGE('PLEASE CHECK THE BOX');
 MESSAGE(' ');
END IF;
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms - as far as I can remember - behaves *strange* regarding the default checkbox value. Although you say that (if unchecked) it is equal to `N`, it is actually *empty* (null). I'd suggest you to try to set the default value upon form startup, for example in `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, e.g.

```
:we_group.check_box_hof := 'N';
```

Alternatively/aditionally, in a trigger whose code you posted, use `NVL` function as

```
if nvl(:we_group.check_box_hof, 'N') = 'N' then
   ...
end if;
```

Comment: We actually discourage the use of checkboxes in our application because the user cannot tell whether it is unset, or unchecked.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the Initial Value property of the checkbox also solve the problem?

Comment: See my first sentence, @Andy. Checkboxes are nice, but pain to work with.